# Blurring svg shapes as they pass through clip path

Tags: svg

Example below:

[image: example]

I'd like to maintain a fixed area in the middle that has svg `circle`s being animated through it.

Most examples I've seen involve some sort of merge that ends up showing both the original circle and the blurred version. Led me to something like this:

```
<clipPath id="top-mask">
  <rect id="top-mask-rect" x="0" y="-100" width="100" height="100" />
</clipPath>

<filter id="top-blur" x="-200%" y="-200%" width="500%" height="500%">
  <feimage xlinkHref="url(#top-mask)" result="mask" />
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.5" result="blur" />

  <feComposite in2="mask" in="blur" operator="in" result="comp" />

  <feMerge result="merge">
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    <feMergeNode in="comp" />
  </feMerge>
</filter>
```

This seems to overlay the circles on top of a slightly blurred version. My next naive step was to remove the `feComposite` and instead apply `clipPath` to both `feMergeNode` which didn't work at all.

What is the correct approach to this problem?

Comment: Set the width and x of the filter, you don't seem to need clipping.

Comment: Width and x is relative to the thing being blurred, not the global space. In this case I am blurring the circles.

Comment: Depends on the units, use userSpaceOnUse units and it's the global space.

Comment: @RobertLongson seems like if you do this, things outside of the filter area don't render

Comment: Yes, you'd have to render them again either outside or inside via a use element as the answer proposes.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help @RobertLongson

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things are not that elementary. You have to stack things a bit on top of one another for this to work. You need a mask to show the un-blurred object outside, and a filter to show it inside the designated area. Both need units defined as `userSpaceOnUse`.

```css
#moving {
  animation: move 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
    0% { transform: translate(0px, 0px) }
   50% { transform: translate(300px, 0px) }
  100% { transform: translate(0px, 0px) }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     height="300" width="500">
  <defs>
  <mask id="mask"
        maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <rect id="still" x="150" y="0" width="200" height="300" fill="black" />
  </mask>
    <filter id="blur" x="150" y="0" width="200" height="300"
            filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#mask)">
    <circle id="moving" r="60" cy="150" cx="100" fill="blue" />
  </g>
  <g filter="url(#blur)">
    <use xlink:href="#moving" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

The way the filter works is interesting. It seems the object is clipped *before* the blur is applied, resulting in a blur near the border of the designated area instead of a hard cut. I am unsure whether to call this a bug or expected behavior. (A quick test showed this both for Firefox and Chrome.)